# Toggle visibility (from 2 DIVs; if 1 DIV is visible, the other shouldn't be and vice versa)

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a toggle menu. 2 hyperlinks for 2 divs.

I found below code from web. It works as intended. Since I want only 1 of my div to be visible, I tried to edit the code. I don't know Javascript. I tried to write it similar to PHP.

For the time being code doesn't work. (It does nothing onclick)

**original code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'none') 
    e.style.display = 'block'; 
    else e.style.display = 'none';}
</script>
```

**edited, nonworking code**

In default, both DIVs are hidden.

I require 'only 1 to be visible simultaneously.'

*NOTE:* the 2 ID info for the 2 divs are:

1. search
2. menu

I know the code below won't be sufficient even it was OK but can you tell me where am I wrong for the time being?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e == 'menu' && e.style.display == 'none') 
        {
            e.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('search').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
        else if (e == 'search' && e.style.display == 'none') 
        {
            e.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you mean `id`, not `e` on lines 4 and 10

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (id == 'menu' && e.style.display == 'none') 
            ^^
        {
            e.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('search').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
        else if (id == 'search' && e.style.display == 'none') 
                 ^^
        {
            e.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got it, thanks, regards. (will accept after 8 min. +1 for quick reply.)

Comment: You're so kind, thanks but this Q doesn't deserve +vote I think.